# Magento 2 top.links loads and then disappears

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, extend

I am learning Magento 2 theme and I am playing with layout. 
My goals is to move account links (Default welcome msg, Sign In, My account etc etc) into the navbar.

I used Magento Luma as parent theme for my theme and added default.xml layout as the following.

#### app/design/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" >
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.panel"  remove="true"></referenceBlock>
        <move element="top.links" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-" as="navigation.account.links" ></move>
    </body>
</page>
```

It works but when the page is loading the links are placed into the nav, after the page stop loading they disappear, any suggestion?

And if i wanted to place the account links inside an icon, how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Any javascript involved in this? What does the web browser console tells you?

Comment: @nicolallias no js involved, neither error on the console.